# Webサイトを作るとき　phpにhtmlを埋め込むか、htmlにphpを埋め込むか

Tags: php, html

初心者です。
webサイトを作っているのですが、
タイトルの通り、どちらが正しいやり方なのでしょうか？

htaccessファイルを用意するとhtmlにphpを埋め込むことが出来て、
phpでもprint関数等を使ってhtmlを出力することが出来るかと思います。

この二つの違いを教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

htmlにphpを埋め込むと仰っているのは、この記事のようなことですよね。

[.htaccessを使って、PHPを拡張子.htmlで動かす方法 | それからデザイン スタッフブログ](http://sole-color-blog.com/blog/php/48/)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

この設定は、.htaccessの効果が及ぶ範囲において**拡張子.htmlを持つファイルをPHPスクリプトとして処理する**というものです。ですからHTMLにPHPを埋め込むという表現は語弊がありますし、しいていえばPHPはHTML文章にプログラムを埋め込むスクリプト言語です。

拡張子.phpがPHPスクリプトとして扱われるのも、同様の設定が（.htaccessとは別の場所で）行われていることによるものですから、PHPの実行に関して違いが出ることはないでしょう。

ただしPHP部分を含まないHTMLもPHPインタプリタで処理されることになりますから、Webサーバーの構成によってはそのような場面のパフォーマンスに若干違いが出るかもしれません。

特に理由がなければ拡張子 .php のままで問題ない、というぐらいでしょうか。