# atomでhtmlファイルにphpを埋め込む方法

Tags: php, html, atom-editor

atomでhtmlにphpを埋め込みたいのですが出来ません。

以下のようなファイルを表示させると

```
aiueo
"; ?>
```

のように表示されてしまいます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>あいうえお</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  echo "<p>aiueo</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

原因がわかる方教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

拡張子を.htmlで作成していませんか？
以下の質問でも似たようなものがありますが、拡張子.htmlをもつファイルをPHPスクリプトとして処理する場合には.htaccessを使用する必要があります。

[Webサイトを作るとき　phpにhtmlを埋め込むか、htmlにphpを埋め込むか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27005/web%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D-php%E3%81%ABhtml%E3%82%92%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%E3%81%8B-html%E3%81%ABphp%E3%82%92%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%E3%81%8B)